# Extracting Smartphone Data From a Webpage

Tags: data-request

I'm try to do some data analysis on smartphone prices but am having trouble finding a dataset. The data found [here](https://www.productchart.com/smartphones/) looks like exactly what I need, but it's in this interactive chart format. I was wondering if there was a way to extract the data put into this chart as a .csv file so that I can use it in SAS and R for data analysis. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it. As shown on the Figure below, the webpage generates special links for each phone, so when you filter the smartphones, you need to extract the data for all results smartphones. This can be do it with scrapping techniques maybe with a python based code.

[image]

Comment: not even that, you can just view source and copy/pasta! its all embedded in a script, but in html and all viewable. i'd copy it out, paste into new html document and open it up in the browser.

Comment: its also exposed in a url as javascript/json. i appended '1000' at the end of this url, because its asking for a number for 'limit=', so results may vary, you may want to tinker with that variable: https://www.productchart.com/smartphones/data?region=com&category=smartphones&limit=1000